# Issue regarding filter in wso2esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2dss3.1.0 and wso2esb 4.7.0.

I wish to filter the condition for that I have user filter mediator.

My proxy is like :

```
   <filter xpath="get-property('mailid1')=''">
            <then>
               <log level="custom">
                  <property name="service called" value="then of inner filter"/>
                  <property name="mailid exist" value="creating new entry in muser with phonenumber as username"/>
               </log>
               <payloadFactory>
                  <format>
                     <p:Capp_insert_emercontactid xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                        <p:username>$1</p:username>
                        <p:firstname>$2</p:firstname>
                        <p:lastname>$3</p:lastname>
                        <p:phonenumber>$4</p:phonenumber>
                        <p:mailid>$5</p:mailid>
                     </p:Capp_insert_emercontactid>
                  </format>
                  <args>
                     <arg expression="get-property('phoneno1')" evaluator="xml"/>

                     <arg expression="get-property('firstname')" evaluator="xml"/>
                     <arg expression="get-property('lastname')" evaluator="xml"/>
                     <arg expression="get-property('phoneno1')" evaluator="xml"/>
                     <arg expression="get-property('mailid1')" evaluator="xml"/>
                  </args>
               </payloadFactory>
               <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
               <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
               <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" action="remove" scope="axis2"/>
               <log level="full"/>
               <send receive="UpdateEmergencyContact_seq3">
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/Capp_MuserDataservice/" format="soap11"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </then>
            <else>
               <log level="custom">
                  <property name="service called" value="else of inner filter"/>
                  <property name="Phonenumber exist" value="creating new entry in muser with mailid as username"/>
               </log>
               <payloadFactory>
                  <format>
                     <p:Capp_insert_emercontactid xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                        <p:username>$1</p:username>
                        <p:firstname>$2</p:firstname>
                        <p:lastname>$3</p:lastname>
                        <p:phonenumber>$4</p:phonenumber>
                        <p:mailid>$5</p:mailid>
                     </p:Capp_insert_emercontactid>
                  </format>
                  <args>
                     <arg expression="get-property('mailid1')" evaluator="xml"/>
                     <arg expression="get-property('firstname')" evaluator="xml"/>
                     <arg expression="get-property('lastname')" evaluator="xml"/>
                     <arg expression="get-property('phoneno1')" evaluator="xml"/>
                     <arg expression="get-property('mailid1')" evaluator="xml"/>
                  </args>
               </payloadFactory>
               <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
               <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
               <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" action="remove" scope="axis2"/>
               <log level="full"/>
               <send receive="UpdateEmergencyContact_seq3">
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/Capp_MuserDataservice/" format="soap11"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </else>
         </filter>
```

I wish to do:

1. If mailid and phonenumber present in request then insert mailid as
   username.
2. If only mailid present insert it as username.
3. if mailid absent insert phonenumber as username.

and configuration I have written is eorkinh fine for else part.

When mailid present proxy allow to insert it as username.

But **problem occurred while mailid absent.In this case it sends  blank username.**. Even not accept hardcoded value.

Log for above at server side is like:

```
 [2014-06-25 10:29:29,676]  INFO - LogMediator phoneno1 = 111, mailid1 =  
[2014-06-25 10:29:29,677]  INFO - LogMediator service called = else of inner filter, Phonenumber exist = creating new entry in muser with mailid as username
[2014-06-25 10:29:29,681]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:f7e63fab-168c-4364-b49b-6c68d6e84eff, Direction: response, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><p:Capp_insert_emercontactid xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"><p:username> </p:username><p:firstname>y1</p:firstname><p:lastname>y2</p:lastname><p:phonenumber/><p:mailid> </p:mailid></p:Capp_insert_emercontactid></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2014-06-25 10:29:29,723]  INFO - LogMediator service called = UpdateEmergencyContact_seq3, userid exist = updating appusers emergency contact with newly insert userid, userid of new entry = 391529635516515404
```

Where is exact problem?

Am I missing something or doing some wrong while writing filter?

Please let me know soon.

Answer (score 0):

it is simple error ..In your else condition . you are passing mail id as username..So, if mailid is not there, username also empty. Check your payload fcatory argument expression

Comment: But as per my configuration if mailid is not exist,then part should get execute..

Comment: yes, so you create payload like   <p:username>$1</p:username> and the argument for that is <arg expression="get-property('mailid1')" evaluator="xml"/>, so if mailid is empty your username also empty

Comment: thnx for reply..my scenario is..if mailid not exist i have to insert phonenumber as username..for this i have made configuration in then part otherwise else part should get execute

Answer (score 0):

in your filter xpath use `boolean(get-property('mailid1'))` and compare it with true and false.